# Задача с массивами

Tags: c, массивы, исследование

Даны три последовательности `X`, `Y`, `Z` из `n` действительных чисел каждая (`n < 200`). Вычислить величину `(а,a) - (b,c)`, где а обозначает ту из последовательностей `X`, `Y`, `Z`, в которой имеется самый большой минимальный элемент, а `b` и `c` означают две другие последовательности.

Вообще не понимаю, что такое `(a,a) - (b,c)`, поэтому для начала решил написать программу, что бы она просто выбрала `a`.

Вопрос такой: как сделать, чтобы в качестве `a` был взят массив с наибольшим минимальным элементом?
Мой код:

```
#define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<locale.h>
#define n 200
void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
    float X[n], Y[n], Z[n];
    int k, i, j, l;
    printf("введите k \n");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    {
        printf("\n Введите значения массива X\n");

        for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
            scanf("%f", &X[i]);

        int min = X[0];

        for (i = 1; i < k; i++) if (X[i] < min) min = X[i];

        printf("\n Минимальный элемент массива X: %d", min);
    }
    {
        printf("\n Введите значения массива Y\n");

        for (j = 0; j < k; j++)
            scanf("%f", &Y[j]);

        int min2 = Y[0];

        for (j = 1; j < k; j++) if (Y[j] < min2) min2 = Y[j];

        printf("\n Минимальный элемент массива Y: %d", min2);
    }
    {
        printf("\n Введите значения массива Z\n");

        for (l = 0; l < k; l++)
            scanf("%f", &Z[l]);

        int min3 = Z[0];

        for (l = 1; l < k; l++) if (Z[l] < min3) min3 = X[l];

        printf("\n Минимальный элемент %d", min3);
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: (a,a) это [Скалярное произведение векторов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, например, так:

```
// Вычисление минимального элемента массива
float min_el(float* a, int n)
{
    float min = a[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
        if (a[i] < min) min = a[i];
    return min;
}

// Выбор массива с максимвльным минимальным элементом.
float* max_min_el(float*a, float*b, float*c, int n)
{
    float ma = min_el(a,n);
    float mb = min_el(b,n);
    float mc = min_el(c,n);
    // Выбираем a
    float m = ma;
    float*p = a;
    if (m < mb) // Если b больше - сохраняем его
    {
        p = b;
        m = mb;
    }
    if (m < mc) // Если c еще больше - выбираем его
        p = c;
    return p;
}
```

Ну, а если (a,a) - действительно скалярное произведение, то

```
float product(float*a, float*b, int n)
{
    float s = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        s += a[i]*b[i];
    return s;
}

float task(float*a, float*b, float*c, int n)
{
    float * m = max_min_el(a,b,c,n);
    if (m == a) return product(a,a,n) - product(b,c,n);
    if (m == b) return product(b,b,n) - product(a,c,n);
    return product(c,c,n) - product(b,a,n);
}
```

Примерно так.

Comment: А как я написал вычислять минимальный элемент массива можно? А для выбора максимального минимального элемента уже создать подпрограмму?

Answer (score 0):

В вашей программе вы сначала объявили массивы переменной длины, при этом не инициализировав переменную `n`, а затем по ошибке вводите значение переменной `k`

```
float X[n], Y[n], Z[n];
       ^^^   ^^^   ^^^
int k, i,j,l;
printf("введите k \n");
scanf("%d", &k);
```

Поэтому ваша программа имеет неопределенное поведение. Вы сначала должны ввести положительное значение переменной `n`, алишь затем объявлять массивы переменной длины.

Что касается вашего вопроса

> Вопрос такой: как сделать, что бы за a взялся массив с наибольшим
>   минимальным элементом?

то вы это можете сделать с помощью указателей на первые элементы массивов. Для упрощения работы можно объявить структуру, которая имеет два поля: минимальное значение в массиве и указатель на массив. Затем просто объявить массив этих структур, соответствующий числу исходных массивов, и отсортировать его.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа. В ней не ищется минимальный элемент массивов, а предполагается, что он уже найден. В результате работы программы массив структур будет отсортирован в соответствии с максимальным минимальным элементом, как это видно по выводу программы. Для простоты в примере также объявлены массивы фиксированного размера.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 3

int main( void )
{
    int a[N] = { 2, 2, 2 };
    int b[N] = { 3, 3, 3 };
    int c[N] = { 1, 1, 1 };

    int a_min = 2;
    int b_min = 3;
    int c_min = 1;

    struct Pair
    {
        int min;
        int *p;
    } min[] = { { a_min, a }, { b_min, b }, { c_min, c } };

    if (min[0].min < min[1].min)
    {
        struct Pair tmp = min[0];
        min[0] = min[1];
        min[1] = tmp;
    }

    if (min[1].min < min[2].min)
    {
        struct Pair tmp = min[1];
        min[1] = min[2];
        min[2] = tmp;
    }

    if (min[0].min < min[1].min)
    {
        struct Pair tmp = min[0];
        min[0] = min[1];
        min[1] = tmp;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("minimum %d: ", min[i].min);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", min[i].p[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
minimum 3: 3 3 3
minimum 2: 2 2 2
minimum 1: 1 1 1
```

Comment: >В вашей программе вы сначала объявили массивы переменной длины, при этом не инициализировав переменную n, а затем по ошибке вводите значение переменной k.                                                          Так у меня же #define n 200, разве так нельзя?

Comment: @Александр Я не заметил. Препроцессорные имена радо объявлять заглавными буквами. Тогда  их сразу же модно отличить от переменных.

Comment: Окей. Можно пару вопросов по вашей программе? Не совсем понимаю, что такое "tmp"?

Comment: @Александр Это "промежуточный" объект структуры, используемый, чтобы обменять значения между двумя объектами этой структуры, например, min[0] и min[1]